# Create a 2D array from terminal(unix)

Tags: unix

I want to create a 2D array. For example free -h gives me a table. I want to create the same table with 2D array without awk. How can I declare it with declare -a matrix . Thanks Community

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: i think i have to use head,tail or sed commands

Comment: Why are you willing to use head, tail, or sed, but unwilling to use awk?  That makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box, but you can simulate it as explained it below, the catch is when you are looping through you need to pass every line to another array

Example data has file names and columns for these

```
browser browserId browserName
country countryId countryName
event eventId eventName
```

Your array declaration will be

```
myArray=(
"browser browserId browserName"
"country countryId countryName"
"event eventId eventName")
```

If you like to create a loop to process each line

```
for afile in "${myArray[@]}"
   do    
   aline=($afile)
   filename=${aline[0]}
   column1=${aline[1]}
   column2=${aline[2]}
done
```

the line

```
afile=($afile)
```

passes each line from myArray to another array called aline.

I have used this and works. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions